# VideoTransformEffectDefinition ends with Error: Video could not be decoded

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, video-processing, video-effects

I am trying to use [VideoTransformEffectDefinition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.media.effects.videotransformeffectdefinition) .

```
        var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(pickedFile);//creating clip from storage file
        MediaComposition composition = new MediaComposition();
        composition.Clips.Add(clip);
        VideoTransformEffectDefinition videoEffect1 = new VideoTransformEffectDefinition();
        videoEffect1.PaddingColor = Colors.Blue;//this line is not necessary, does not matter how videoEffect is changed 
        clip.VideoEffectDefinitions.Add(videoEffect1);//adding videoEffect
        this.mediaElement.SetMediaStreamSource(composition.GenerateMediaStreamSource());//setting source to MediaElement
```

This is not going to throw exception but it show me

> "Error: Video could not be decoded"

on media element.

It is strange, because code is working well with [VideoStabilizationEffectDefinition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn926762?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
        var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(pickedFile);//creating clip from storage file
        MediaComposition composition = new MediaComposition();
        composition.Clips.Add(clip);
        VideoStabilizationEffectDefinition videoEffect = new VideoStabilizationEffectDefinition();
        clip.VideoEffectDefinitions.Add(videoEffect);//adding videoEffect
        this.mediaElement.SetMediaStreamSource(composition.GenerateMediaStreamSource());//setting source to MediaElement
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`VideoTransformEffectDefinition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.effects.videotransformeffectdefinition.aspx) only works with [`MediaTranscoder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.transcoding.mediatranscoder.aspx). It has no effect over [`MediaComposition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.editing.mediacomposition.aspx). And it throw an NullReferenceException  when you set the `MediaElement` by `MediaElement.SetMediaStreamSource(MediaComposition .GenerateMediaStreamSource())`.

There is an official sample from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MediaTranscoding) that uses the `MediaTranscoder`. And in Scenario1, it creates the `MediaTranscoder` by `private MediaTranscoder _Transcoder = new MediaTranscoder();` You can add the  `VideoTransformEffectDefinition` to `MediaTranscoder` by [`AddAudioEffect(System.String activatableClassId, System.Boolean effectRequired, IPropertySet configuration)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.transcoding.mediatranscoder.addaudioeffect.aspx).

You can add the following code to `TranscodePreset` event in Scenario1_Default.xaml.cs.

For example:

```
VideoTransformEffectDefinition videoEffect = new VideoTransformEffectDefinition();
_Transcoder.ClearEffects();
var activatableClassId = videoEffect.ActivatableClassId;
_Transcoder.AddVideoEffect(activatableClassId, true, videoEffect.Properties);
videoEffect.PaddingColor = Colors.Blue;
videoEffect.Rotation = MediaRotation.Clockwise90Degrees;
```

Comment: So.. it means it is not possible to add (for example) padding color in real time? Official sample is always with saving to storage file..

Comment: It seems it is, I do not find the method to play in real time.